# Infinite loop when I updated query to add an additional variable

Tags: postgresql, infinite-loop, exists

I have this query:

```
    with users_having_connected as (
    select u.id as user_id,
           (a.connected_at is not null) has_connected
    from core_user u
    join core_profile p on u.id = p.user_id
    join core_conversation c on (c.profile1_id = p.id or c.profile2_id = p.id)
    join analytics_connection a on c.id = a.conversation_id
    group by u.id, (a.connected_at is not null)
)
select u.id as user_id,
       date_trunc('month', u.created at time zone 'UTC')::date as month,
       p.community_id,
       p.organization_id,
       p.profile_type_intention,
       (p.basic_account_completed and (p.is_mentor or p.is_entrepreneur)) as profile_is_completed,
       exists(select 1 from core_message where core_message.sender_id = p.id) as has_sent_a_message,
       (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM core_message WHERE core_message.receiver_id = p.id)) AS has_received_a_message,
       (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM core_admin_conversation_w_resp WHERE core_admin_conversation_w_resp.initiator_id = p.id or core_admin_conversation_w_resp.responder_id = p.id)) AS has_one_by_one,
       exists(select 1 from users_having_connected where user_id = u.id) as has_two_by_two
from core_user as u
join core_profile p on u.id = p.user_id
where
p.profile_type_intention is not null
```

Which worked fine until I added this line:

```
(EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM core_admin_conversation_w_resp WHERE core_admin_conversation_w_resp.initiator_id = p.id or core_admin_conversation_w_resp.responder_id = p.id)) AS has_one_by_one,
```

This specific variable add causes this query to infinite loop. What do I need to do to fix it? Am I missing a set of parentheses somewhere?

Comment: Is this part of a bigger query as I don't see how this would run period?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I think I updated it so that it is the full query. There was a part missing from the quotation earlier, thank you for catching that.

Comment: What do get when you run `EXPLAIN  with users_having_connected as ...` ?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am not sure I understand your question, can you elaborate?

Comment: [Explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) will tell you what the Postgres planner is doing with query without actually running it. Post the results as update to your question. For the moment do not use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` as that actually runs the query and you won't get any information.